# Error Connecting to Databricks from local machine

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am attempting to make a connection to Databricks from my Mac(Mojave).

I did a `pip install -U databricks-connect==5.5.*`

I start a spark-shell but when I try to query in spark I get the following error

Caused by: com.databricks.service.SparkServiceConnectionException: Invalid token

```
To connect to a Databricks cluster, you must specify an API token.
API Token: The API token used to confirm your identity to Databricks
  - Learn more about API tokens here: https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/authentication.html#generate-a-token
  - Get current value: spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.token")
  - Set via conf: spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.service.token", <your API token>)
  - Set via environment variable: export DATABRICKS_API_TOKEN=<your API token>
```

I then run spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.token") and I get back the token I created. We tried using this token on a windows machine and it works.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new token and using it?

Comment: yes, I sure have.

Comment: How do you usually feed the token to spark? Via conf file, environment vairable, or spark.conf.set?

Comment: I'm using dbconnect through conda. There is a databricks-connect configure command where the host name, cluster name, token etc are configured.

Comment: I trust you have been following [this documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html) what does `databricks-connect test` return?

Comment: yes sir. I get the same error that is posted in the question.

Comment: And when you re-run `databricks-connect configure` again it still provides a valid token? Did you uninstall before doing all that?

Comment: Not during this round but I've done it before I posted the question.

Comment: This seems to be a Mac issue. I had a coworker create a new token and attempt to connect but it did not work.

Comment: Hope you find a workaround, I had no issues with either Windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
databricks-connect configure
```

Follow the steps on the command prompt. You will be asked to enter your `Databricks Token`, enter your token, follow remaining steps and it should be resolved.

PS: When you are asked to enter your `Databricks Host:` provide a generic hostname for the region followed by your org-id. For example:

`https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net/?o=xxxx` instead of `https://adb-xxxx.xy.azuredatabricks.net/?o=xxxx`